# Move View in WindowManager makes the view not appear

Tags: android, gridview, view, drag-and-drop, android-windowmanager

I'm using DynGridView by PocketMagic to dynamically drag/drop views in grid view. Once I start dragging the DragView is created from a bitmap, added to WindowManager and shown on the screen. The problem is that the view doesn't appear if I start dragging the view fast. It appears only if I start dragging slow or stop moving for a while. Here is the code responsible for adding the view to WindowManager and moving the dragged view.

```
/**
 * Create a window containing this view and show it.
 *
 * @param windowToken obtained from v.getWindowToken() from one of your views
 * @param touchX the x coordinate the user touched in screen coordinates
 * @param touchY the y coordinate the user touched in screen coordinates
 */
 public void show(IBinder windowToken, int touchX, int touchY) {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp;
    int pixelFormat;
    pixelFormat = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

    lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            touchX-mRegistrationX, touchY-mRegistrationY,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_SUB_PANEL,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    pixelFormat);
    lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    lp.token = windowToken;
    lp.setTitle("DragView");
    mLayoutParams = lp;

    mWindowManager.addView(this, lp);
 }

/**
 * Move the window containing this view.
 *
 * @param touchX the x coordinate the user touched in screen coordinates
 * @param touchY the y coordinate the user touched in screen coordinates
 */
 void move(int touchX, int touchY) {
     // This is what was done in the Launcher code.
     WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = mLayoutParams;
     lp.x = touchX - mRegistrationX;
     lp.y = touchY - mRegistrationY;
     mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(this, lp);
 }
```

Commenting these lines

```
//lp.x = touchX - mRegistrationX;
//lp.y = touchY - mRegistrationY;
```

or

```
//mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(this, lp);
```

makes the view appear everytime, so I guess that it is somehow related to fast movement right after the view  has been added to the WindowManager.

As for the log, the following line is shown when the problem happens:

```
V/ViewRootImpl: dispatchResized mReportNextDraw cancel... mWinFrame : Rect(837, 129 - 911, 189)  frame : Rect(653, 194 - 727, 254) window DragView
```

If any other information is required, let me know!

**EDIT:**
I face this issue on Android 4.4. There is no problem on Android 5.0.